# Android EpoxyRecyclerView - switching orientation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I am trying to build the following layout structure with Epoxy:

[image]

First three layouts are from EpoxyAModel.
The fourth one is from the EpoxyBModel.

This is my buildModels function:

```
override fun buildModels() {

    aModels.forEach { //this happens 3 times
        modelA {
            id("someID")
            (...)

        }
    }

    modelB {
        id("someID2")
        (...)
    }

}
```

With this set up I am getting the following result:

[image]

This is understandable, since the documentation of `EpoxyRecyclerView` says:

> If the RecyclerView is set to match_parent size then the scrolling
>   orientation is set to vertical and setHasFixedSize is set to true.
>
> If the height is set to wrap_content then the scrolling orientation is
>   set to horizontal, and setClipToPadding is set to false for carousel
>   usage.

My question is: is there a possibility of getting the desired effect or do I have to define another `EpoxyRecyclerView` and controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out!

Firstly, we need to assign a `GridLayoutManager` to the `EpoxyRecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
```

Then, inside the `EpoxyBModel` we need to override the `getSpanSize` method to tell the layout manager that this element is as big as a whole row of items:

```
override fun getSpanSize(totalSpanCount: Int, position: Int, itemCount: Int): Int = 3
```